# Node crash calling c# dll's method from native addon

Tags: javascript, c#, c++, node.js

I tried to build a C# dll(.NET Framework 4) with simple Hello World method in it. This is the code:

```
using System;
namespace ClassLibrary1
{
    public class Class1
    {
        public static void Hello()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
        }
    }
}
```

Then I called this dll from C++. All went fine when I built it but, when I tried to call `hello` method from javascript, terminal didn't output anything. I did this way:

Origine.cc:

```
#include <node.h>
#using <../ClassLibrary1.dll>

#pragma unmanaged

using namespace v8;
void Greet();
void Method(const FunctionCallbackInfo<Value>& args) {
  Isolate* isolate = args.GetIsolate();
  Greet();
  args.GetReturnValue().Set(Boolean::New(isolate, true));
}
void init(Local<Object> exports) {
  NODE_SET_METHOD(exports, "hello", Method);
}
NODE_MODULE(NODE_GYP_MODULE_NAME, init)

#pragma managed

void Greet(){
    ClassLibrary1::Class1::Hello();
}
```

binding.gyp

```
{
  "targets": [
  {
    "target_name": "addon",
    "sources": [ "Origine.cc" ],
    "msbuild_settings": {
      "ClCompile": {
        "CompileAsManaged": "true",
        "ExceptionHandling": "Async",
      }
    }
  }]
}
```

test.js

```
require ('./build/Release/addon').hello();
```

Files in folder:

```
Origine.cc
binding.gyp
ClassLibrary1.dll
test.js
```

I'm on Windows 10 64-bit and I'm using Node 7.10.0
Any help to get it work is appreciated

Comment: are you sure you can call this method in c++ without marking it as COM visible?

Comment: @Steve yes, I'm sure because I tried with a simple C++/CLI tester and it works

Comment: you probably marked that c++ program to be run using .net framework. Native c++ code requires c# program to be marked as COM to be usable. Node does NOT run on .net framework and thus you can't call the managed code directly

Comment: @Steve Tried to follow (https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/695387/Calling-Csharp-NET-methods-from-unmanaged-C-Cplusp)[this] tutorial to wrap C# code in a C++/CLI dll and call this one from unmanaged C++ but didn't work